# symfony: error when I call url_for() inside <script> tags

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm calling url_for() inside these javascript tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.post('<?php echo url_for('category_set_representative_image',
array('sf_subject' => $category)) ?>',
           function(){

             alert("fadsf");
           }
    );

</script>
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
sfError404Exception: Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL
'/rappresentativa' (/).
```

I have also this routing rule:

```
category_set_representative_image:
  url:     /rappresentativa
  param:   { module: category_new, action: setRepresentativeImage }
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: Category, type: object }
```

NOTE: I don't have problems if I call the same url_for() far from the
 tags.

Any idea?

sf 1.4

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://symfonyexperts.com/question/show/id/113) does work:

```
category_set_representative_image:
  url:     /rappresentativa
  param:  { module: category_new, action: setRepresentativeImage}
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: Category, type: object }
  requirements: { sf_method: post }
```

**EDIT**: anyway is also necessary what antonkalyaev says:

```
category_set_representative_image:
  url:     /rappresentativa/:id
  param:  { module: category_new, action: setRepresentativeImage}
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: Category, type: object }
  requirements: { sf_method: post }
```

Javi

Answer (score 2):

The error you've described above not related to the `script` tags. It's don't matter where do you use it (url_for).

**First**, I think, you need to use `url_for(array('sf_route' => 'category_set_representative_image', 'sf_subject' => $category))` **OR** just `url_for('category_set_representative_image', $category)`. The first is useful when you need to pass more arguments than just the object. [More](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/05)

**Second** (less important), maybe you need to add more params to your URL:

```
category_set_representative_image:
  url:     /rappresentativa/:id
  param:   { module: category_new, action: setRepresentativeImage }
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: Category, type: object }
  requirements:
    id: \d+
```

**Third**, check that module and action really exists:

```
// apps/<application>/category_new/actions.class.php
public function executeSetRepresentativeImage(sfWebrRequest $request) {
  $category = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
```

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is just related to misusage of quotes between javascript and PHP.
Try it like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.post('<?php echo url_for("category_set_representative_image",
array("sf_subject" => $category)) ?>',
       function(){

         alert("fadsf");
       }
);
```